# WordPress - check if have posts on front-page.php

Tags: wordpress

I have got a WordPress installation and created a `front-page.php` - I have to check there if the blog has posted.

have_posts() returns always 1, although no blog-posts were published.

Answer (score 0):

This code will help you to show the published post.

`if( have_posts() ) :
    while( have_posts() ) : the_post();
        echo get_the_title()."<br>";
    endwhile;
else :
    _e( 'Sorry, no posts were found.', 'textdomain' );
endif;`

Answer (score 0):

No, this snippet does not help me.

I have to check if there are posts from blog via own query. I had a missunderstanding what have_posts() does.